# Deploy from gitlab pipeline to IIS in shared server - .Net Core 2.2 application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to deploy my code from gitlab to my shared server IIS running under Plesk.
It is a .Net Core 2.2 application.
I tried on the pipeline the command.

```
publish-to-dev:
  stage: publish-to-dev
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-focal
  #image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
  script:
    - 'dotnet build'
    - 'dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile="devCoreMoocapps2" /p:Username="$MsDeployUserName" /p:Password="$MsDeployPassword" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true'
```

Where `$MsDeployUserName` and `$MsDeployPassword` are variables defined in gitlab.
I am getting the following error

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.414/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(171,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid.
```

Looks like the path is not valid: **"%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid.**

Do you guys have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: This error occurs when an executable for a task could not be found. An MSBuild task that runs a tool typically fails if there is an installation problem with the tool or package that provides the tool. To resolve this error: Check the executable to make sure it's installed at the expected path. More information you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb6004?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb6004?view=vs-2019).